# C++ С чего начать?

Tags: c++

С чего начать изучение C++? Мне 14 лет. Математику знаю хорошо. Привлекает как написание сайтов, так и написание программ. Знаю php, но плохо (по урокам Попова).

Comment: начать с того, что почитать подобные вопросы
[1](http://hashcode.ru/questions/12767/), [2](http://hashcode.ru/questions/27415/)

Comment: @KoVadim ну всё-таки изучение языка вообще не зная программирования или зная основы - это разные вещи. От сюда и идут мои строки в ответе:

> В книге сначала будет про всякие if -ы, циклы, переменные и т.д. Тут приглядывайся к синтаксису (где какая кавычка и т.д.). Дальше ты увидишь ООП. Отсюда изучай повнимательнее.

Comment: >Знаю php, но плохо (по урокам Попова)

уроки Попова - это не просто нулевые, это отрицательные знания

Comment: @DreamChild Ну-ка на днях посмотрю. Если в вкратце, что там плохого?

Comment: там плохо все. От дурных и устаревших советов до в корне неправильной подачи обучения, в результате чего на выходе получается "погромист", свято верящий в свою крутость, но не способный ни на что кроме стряпания сайтов-визиток, а что еще более ужасно - практика показывает, что этих индивидуумов уже ничто не способно исправить, кроме электрошоковой терапии. В принципе, творчество г-на Попова - это и не уроки вовсе ,а способ срубить бабок с балбесов, которым не жалко за это барахло заплатить. Если не лень - погуглите, в интернете есть немало соответствующих статей об этом гуру

Comment: Начать с того, что подумать, а надо ли в 14 лет изучать C++? Может всё-таки какой python? Там и ООП есть, и не только ООП. И мучений меньше. А когда потом потребуется C++, изучать его будет уже легче. И C++'ных заскоков будет меньше.

Comment: @alexlz, согласен. Особенно если 

>Привлекает как написание сайтов

тогда какой уж там C++

Comment: Тут есть список литературы http://habrahabr.ru/qa/37321/

Comment: @Vlmake, если Вы на винде - то, с перехода на \*nix (например, линукс).

Если Вы уже там, то с попытки воспроизвести какую нибудь утилиту командной строки (например, `cp`).

Если прочтете `man cp` и появится желание повторить ее, то многому научитесь.

Comment: Если захочешь уйти в вэб разравботку и уровень знаний низкий, могу посоветовать книгу Роберта Никсона "Создаем веб-сайты с помощью PHP, MySQL и JS." У этого автора удивительный талант просто объяснять сложные вещи (сложные они для новичка).

Comment: можно воспользоваться индийской системой   
http://cs417324.userapi.com/v417324544/124a/KlBwhuABvQU.jpg

Comment: учи джаву и потом переходи на плюсы

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ну, наверное, лучше начать с [Язык программирования C++. Лекции и упражнения](http://www.ozon.ru/context/detail/id/7979735/), потом Страуструп, Мейерс, Саттер и Александреску. Если уж математику хорошо знаете, то можете попробовать себя в олимпиадных задачках [Codeforces](http://codeforces.ru/), вам так же понадобятся знания алгоритмов, [Алгоритмы. Построение и анализ](http://www.ozon.ru/context/detail/id/2429691/) хорошая книга. Если сидите на Windows, то как IDE используйте Visual Studio, если на Linux, то Qt Creator.

Comment: с Александреску вы ,конечно, подзагнули - даже если парень действительно станет серьезно изучать язык, эта фамилия ему понадобится еще ой как не скоро

Comment: с уклоном на будущее отвечал ) 
ну может книги Александреску автор читать и не будет, но все же знать, кто это и что за методы программирования он продвигает, нужно, да и если автор возьмется за С++, то все равно узнает рано или поздно…

Answer (score 1):

Рекомендую начать с книги Герберта Шилдта "Самоучитель Си++". Если будете писать под Windows - Visual Studio, если под Linux - компилятор g++, среда разработки на ваш выбор(если качество важнее скорости вхождения - Vim)